# Get the current date including milli-seconds

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I have to track the current system time including milli-seconds using ColdFusion 11. I am using the `Now()` function but it outputs the date like this `{ts '2017-01-11 06:48:58'}`. I need to include the milli-seconds as well. Please let me know.

Answer (score 4):

The milliseconds are there and you can get to them by using the `TimeFormat()` function of ColdFusion. Here is some sample code showing this:

```
<cfscript>
    currentTime = Now();
    writeOutput('<p>' & currentTime & '</p>');

    formattedTime = TimeFormat(currentTime,'HH:mm:ss.l');
    writeOutput('<p>' & formattedTime & '</p>');
</cfscript>

<!--- which outputs the following --->

{ts '2017-01-11 13:10:03'}

13:10:03.827
```

The first bit of code show the standard display format that you referenced. The second bit uses the `TimeFormat()` function to also include the milliseconds using the `l` mask option.

Here is a gist of that code so you can see it in action - [TimeFormat example on trycf.com](http://trycf.com/gist/9eb6906809257ad7e1de1272734eab64/acf11?theme=monokai)

There are several formatting options available to you using that function.

> Masking characters that determine the format:
>
> - h: hours; no leading zero for single-digit hours (12-hour clock)
> - hh: hours; leading zero for single-digit hours (12-hour clock)
> - H: hours; no leading zero for single-digit hours (24-hour clock)
> - HH: hours; leading zero for single-digit hours (24-hour clock)
> - m: minutes; no leading zero for single-digit minutes
> - mm: minutes; a leading zero for single-digit minutes
> - s: seconds; no leading zero for single-digit seconds
> - ss: seconds; leading zero for single-digit seconds
> - l or L: milliseconds, with no leading zeros
> - t: one-character time marker string, such as A or P
> - tt: multiple-character time marker string, such as AM or PM
> - short: equivalent to h:mm tt
> - medium: equivalent to h:mm:ss tt
> - long: medium followed by three-letter time zone; as in, 2:34:55 PM EST
> - full: same as long

[From the Adobe ColdFusion documentation here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6de0.html)

If you still need the date portion of the object then use the `DateFormat()` function to display that part.

Comment: Yes, do not trust the default string representation of dates and numbers. They are not always completely accurate.  If you need both date and time, on CF11 you can also use [DateTimeFormat](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-c-d/DateTimeFormat.html), ie `DateTimeFormat(currentTime, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:nn:ss.L")`. Note, unlike TimeFormat it uses `n` for hours instead of `m`.

Comment: Lol... good catch.  Not enough caffeine.  Yes, I definitely meant to say `n` for minutes - *not* hours.